# XCode: Deleted file still has a reference somewhere...ut

Tags: swift, xcode

So I deleted a file (LoginViewController) but XCode retained a reference to it. Went through the project and found that the file had not been moved to my trash but was still there. I moved it to the trash, clean, quit, build, same thing. I checked the git repo, all good. Delete derived data, clean, clean build folder, quit, shut down mac, restart, build...same error. Drink beer and think. Not much. Come to SO for the rescue.

So here's the message XCode is giving me:

/Users/***me***/Desktop/Development/***appname***/LoginViewController.swift

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

I got a feeling XC is trying to tell me where the reference to the file is but it's speaking Portugese and I am speaking Quebecois French. Any ideas?

Swift 4/XCode 9.4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure the file reference is removed from the compile sources phase. It is possible for the file to be referenced there but not in the project navigator due to the underlying structure of the pbxproj file.

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thanks!